# Where can I find a bathroom fan that will fit in a 5" cylindrical space?

Tags: fan

The fan in the master-bathroom of my house recently stopped working.

The old fan is in a 5" cylindrical housing in the ceiling and the housing is not going to come out without major work on the ceiling.  Unfortunately all of my local hardware stores only seem to be stocking bathroom/vent fans that fit into 6-7" square housings.

Does anyone know of a place where I can find a smaller size fan?  I'm open to other suggestions as well but I'd prefer to not tear the whole bathroom ceiling apart.

Comment: Can you get at it from the attic, or is it underneath a second story?

Comment: It's upstairs and the upstairs was actually converted from the attic so I can't get at it that way.  It looks like the housing was probably put in when they framed the upstairs and then they did the ceiling around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I lived in a condo built in the early 50's with a super cool looking chrome bathroom exhaust fan.  The original motor finally died after 54 years of service... so I went looking for a replacement fan/light unit.

Unfortunately I was unsuccessful as well since the original fan housing is not the "standard" (read: newer) bathroom exhaust fan size.

Anyway, I was able to find a replacement motor for the exhaust fan assembly and it worked beautifully.  If the motor has any nameplate data on it - odds are you can probably find an equivalent replacement.

I bought mine from this place [Replacement Bath Vent Fan Motors](http://www.electricmotorwarehouse.com/aosmith/nutone/nutone.htm) - just remember it doesn't necessarily have to say "bath vent fan motor" in order to work, so long as the motor nameplate data (volts, amps, HP) are similar.

Good luck!